# Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space. If $f,g\in V^*$ are linearly independent, then find $\dim(\ker f\cap \ker g)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space. If $f,g\in V^*$ are linearly independent, then find $\dim(\ker f\cap \ker g)$.

1. $\dim(\ker f)=\dim(\ker g)=n-1$ because $f,g\neq 0$, correct?
2. Hint for answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Grassmann’s formula,
$$
\dim(\ker f\cap\ker g)=\dim\ker f+\dim\ker g-\dim(\ker f+\ker g)
$$
Now, since $f$ and $g$ are nonzero (because the zero vector does not belong to a linearly independent set),
\begin{align}
\dim\ker f&=n-1\\
\dim\ker g&=n-1
\end{align}

So you're correct, until now.

Since $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent,
$$
\ker f+\ker g=…
$$
because $\ker f\ne\ker g$.

Comment: I don't know $ker f + ker g =...$  
${v+u / f(v)=g(u)=0 }?$

Comment: @Magering Since $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent, $\ker f\ne\ker g$: can you show this? Therefore $\ker f+\ker g$ properly contains both. But both have dimension $n-1$, so…

Answer (score 0):

Yes to 1.

As to 2, consider the restriction of $f$ to $U = \ker(g)$. It is clearly an element of $U^{\star}$. Can it be zero?